# Cytoscape.js zigzag like edges

Tags: javascript, css, graph, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I am trying to create a zigzag like edges in cytoscape.js. I have found [zigzag edges](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/882) on github but I guess it's not yet implemented or it's abandoned, so I am trying to calculate the points but I am having some trouble.
My graph looks like this:[image]

I assume that there are 3 cases here. One when the source is on the left of the target, other when the source and target have same x value and the third case when the source is on the right of the target.

The second case is basic and I have calculated it (just a straight line from source to the target) but I am having trouble calculating the other two cases.

I am trying to make the edges look like this:

[image]

I am using the following function to try to calculate them:

```
cy.elements('edge').css({'segment-distances': 

function(ele){
    var target = ele.target();
    var source = ele.source();
    var source_id = source.data().id;
    var target_id = target.data().id;
    var sou_pos_x = (cy.$('#' + source_id).position('x'));
    var tar_pos_x = (cy.$('#' + target_id).position('x'));
    var sou_pos_y = (cy.$('#' + source_id).position('y'));
    var tar_pos_y = (cy.$('#' + target_id).position('y'));
    var sou_tar_distance_x = (sou_pos_x - tar_pos_x);
    var sou_tar_distance_y = (sou_pos_y - tar_pos_y);

    // source on the left of the target
    if (sou_pos_x < tar_pos_x){
        return 0;
    }
    // source on same position as target
    else if (sou_pos_x == tar_pos_x){
        return 0;
    }
    // source on the right of the target
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
});
```

From what I have read from the documentation on [segments-edges](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/segments-edges), I should have 2 points.

The calculation would have been a lot easier if you could specify coordinates for each segment point. With the way that is right now it's hard to calculate the values perpendicular to the line formed from the source to the target because those values might vary depending how far apart is the source from the target node

Can anyone help me with this issue or at least give me a guidance on how to achieve what I am looking for? I have been stuck with this problem for quite some time.

**EDIT**

I have added:

```
'source-endpoint': '180deg',
'target-endpoint': '0deg'
```

so now the all the edges start and end from same position, which would simplify the calculation.

**EDIT 2:**

This has been implemented by [taxi edges](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/2306) like [this](https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/taxi-edges)